# Task<t>.Wait never returns

Tags: c#, task

I have a problem that I've boiled down to this code snippet:

```
var task=new Task<int>(()=>5);

task.Wait();
```

Problem is `task.Wait()` never returns. I've written code in the past that worked just fine.

What I've tried so far:

- wrapping the whole thing in an async function and calling `Wait` on that (same behavior)
- this was initially a list of promises wrapped in a `WaitAll` and calling `Wait` on that stalled
- tried calling `Task.Start` but received an exception that stated `Task.Start` didn't work with promise style Tasks

So, any ideas?

**Edit:**

Full code snippet that is causing the issue:

```
static void EfTest()
{
    _start = DateTime.Now;
    var task = CreateEfTask();

    var efTasks= Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(i => CreateEfTask()).ToList();

    var t= Task.WhenAll(efTasks);
    t.Wait();

    var results = t.Result;
}

private static Task<Result> CreateEfTask()
{
    return new Task<List<PricingRule>>(
        () => new global::Entities
            .Entities()
            .PricingRules
            .Where(pr => pr.IsEnabled).ToList())
            .ContinueWith(t => new Result 
            {
                PricingRules = t.Result,
                TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_start)
            });
}
```

Putting `Task.Start` before `t.Wait` throws an error saying that you can't use start on a promise stile Task.

Comment: if I do task.Start(); it runs, but its already completed by the time I hit wait. So, then mine runs as expected - I dont get errors

Comment: "tried calling Task.Start but received an exception that stated Task.Start didn't work with promise style Tasks" Can we see the specific exception please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task from `Task.Wait` never ends because the tasks it is waiting on are never started. You need to start them e.g.

```
var efTasks= Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(i => CreateEfTask()).ToList();

foreach(var t in eTasks) {
    t.Start();
}

var t= Task.WhenAll(efTasks);
t.Wait();
```

although you probably want to start it in `CreateEfTask()`:

```
private static Task<List<PricingRule>> CreateEfTask()
{
    var t = new Task<List<PricingRule>>(
        () => new global::Entities.Entities().PricingRules.Where(pr => pr.IsEnabled).ToList()).ContinueWith(t=>new Result {PricingRules = t.Result,TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_start)});
    t.Start();
    return t;
}
```

If this is entity framework, you should be able to execute queries asynchronously without constructing your own tasks and starting them e.g.

```
private static Task<List<PricingRule>> CreateEfTask() {
    return new global::Entities.Entities().PricingRules.Where(pr => pr.IsEnabled).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Figured this out on my own while rereading the MSDN examples. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Something else is wrong somewhere in your app

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task = new Task<int>(() => 5);
            task.Start();
            task.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Runs to completion every time, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't starting the task. You need to call `Start()` on the task before waiting.

You can also use the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method, which is functionally equivalent to creating a Task with the constructor and then starting it, e.g.:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 5);

task.Wait()
```